# AWS - want to upload multiple files to S3 and only when all are uploaded trigger a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-swf

I am seeking advice on what's the best way to design this -

**Use Case**

I want to put multiple files into S3. Once all files are successfully saved, I want to trigger a lambda function to do some other work.

**Naive Approach**

The way I am approaching this is by saving a record in Dynamo that contains a unique identifier and the total number of records I will be uploading along with the keys that should exist in S3.

A basic implementation would be to take my existing lambda function which is invoked anytime my S3 bucket is written into, and have it check manually whether all the other files been saved.

The Lambda function would know (look in Dynamo to determine what we're looking for) and query S3 to see if the other files are in. If so, use SNS to trigger my other lambda that will do the other work.

Edit: Another approach is have my client program that puts the files in S3 be responsible for directly invoking the other lambda function, since technically it knows when all the files have been uploaded. The issue with this approach is that I do not want this to be the responsibility of the client program... I want the client program to not care. As soon as it has uploaded the files, it should be able to just exit out.

**Thoughts**

I don't think this is a good idea. Mainly because Lambda functions should be lightweight, and polling the database from within the Lambda function to get the S3 keys of all the uploaded files and then checking in S3 if they are there - doing this each time seems ghetto and very repetitive.

What's the better approach? I was thinking something like using SWF but am not sure if that's overkill for my solution or if it will even let me do what I want. The documentation doesn't show real "examples" either. It's just a discussion without much of a step by step guide (perhaps I'm looking in the wrong spot).

**Edit** In response to mbaird's suggestions below-

**Option 1 (SNS)** This is what I will go with. It's simple and doesn't really violate the Single Responsibility Principal. That is, the client uploads the files and sends a notification (via SNS) that its work is done.

**Option 2 (Dynamo streams)** So this is essentially another "implementation" of Option 1. The client makes a service call, which in this case, results in a table update vs. a SNS notification (Option 1). This update would trigger the Lambda function, as opposed to notification. Not a bad solution, but I prefer using SNS for communication rather than relying on a database's capability (in this case Dynamo streams) to call a Lambda function.

In any case, I'm using AWS technologies and have coupling with their offering (Lambda functions, SNS, etc.) but I feel relying on something like Dynamo streams is making it an even tighter coupling. Not really a huge concern for my use case but still feels dirty ;D

**Option 3 with S3 triggers** My concern here is the possibility of race conditions. For example, if multiple files are being uploaded by the client simultaneously (think of several async uploads fired off at once with varying file sizes), what if two files happen to finish uploading at around the same time, and two or more Lambda functions (or whatever implementations we use) query Dynamo and gets back N as the completed uploads (instead of N and N+1)?  Now even though the final result should be N+2, each one would add 1 to N. Nooooooooooo!

So Option 1 wins.

Comment: Option 1 is definitely the most elegant solution. I'm glad you are going with that. There should be no race condition in option 3 if you use DynamoDB Atomic Counters, and check the return result of the update instead of performing a separate query. I tried to make that clear in my answer by linking to the atomic counter documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the client program responsible for invoking the Lambda function directly, then would it be OK if it did something a bit more generic?

**Option 1: (SNS)** What if it simply notified an SNS topic that it had completed a batch of S3 uploads? You could subscribe your Lambda function to that SNS topic.

**Option 2: (DynamoDB Streams)** What if it simply updated the DynamoDB record with something like an attribute `record.allFilesUploaded = true`. You could have your Lambda function [trigger off the DynamoDB stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html). Since you are already creating a DynamoDB record via the client, this seems like a very simple way to mark the batch of uploads as complete without having to code in knowledge about what needs to happen next. The Lambda function could then check the "allFilesUploaded" attribute instead of having to go to S3 for a file listing every time it is called.

Alternatively, don't insert the DynamoDB record until all files have finished uploading, then your Lambda function could just trigger off new records being created.

**Option 3: (continuing to use S3 triggers)** If the client program can't be changed from how it works today, then instead of listing all the S3 files and comparing them to the list in DynamoDB each time a new file appears, simply update the DynamoDB record via an [atomic counter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters). Then compare the result  value against the size of the file list. Once the values are the same you know all the files have been uploaded. The down side to this is that you need to provision enough capacity on your DynamoDB table to handle all the updates, which is going to increase your costs.

Also, I agree with you that SWF is overkill for this task.

Comment: Adding comments to my original post regarding your suggestions. Marking this as the answer. I appreciate you writing this out - this is very helpful.

Comment: I'm using third option, invoking lambda function that download object to EFS by S3 trigger and i'm facing the following problem. when i upload multiple files using filezilla client to S3 lambda is well invoked and works, it download files but not all uploaded files, when i check cloudwatch logs i found timeout error on some objects.
error message :

    [ERROR] ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://*bucket_name*.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/*object*

Comment: @Chawki sounds like you should post that as a separate question on this site, instead of trying to get help in the comment section here.