# AWS SNS trigger when 3 objects are loaded into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a client that performs a weekly data upload of 3 CSV files to an S3 bucket, always within (at most) 5 minutes of each other. I have python code that ingests the 3 files, aggregates them, and writes and output that I would like to use to create a lambda function to fully automate this job. The issue is that I can't configure an S3 trigger that is every 3 object creates. I could have the lambda trigger every upload and exit until the 3 files are there but I don't want to do that as it's not really cost effective.

So I came across this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376697/aws-want-to-upload-multiple-files-to-s3-and-only-when-all-are-uploaded-trigger) that suggested having an SNS Topic that gets notified after a batch of uploads is completed, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure that. Basically what I'd like to do is create something similar to a CloudWatch Alarm that triggers when 3 object PUTS have occurred within 5 minutes of each other. Is this possible? Or, how can I configure my SNS event in a way as is suggested in the linked question?

Comment: how about adding a wait time in lambda ??

Comment: the original problem was that I wanted it to trigger once per 3 files. putting in a wait time doesn't solve that. I have been running it with an execution per file in production for 10 months now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misreading the answer in the post you linked. The SNS option is literally someone just sending an SNS message after they have pushed their batch of files to S3. So the sender would need to update their process to include a new SNS message step.

Option 3 in that question/answer is about using S3 triggers to handle this in an automatic fashion, without the sender needing to do any extra steps besides upload files, but it is also much more complicated since it involves using a DynamoDB table with Atomic Counters to ensure the files aren't processed multiple times.

I would like to point out that your concern over the cost effectiveness of triggering a Lambda function for each S3 object is going to be on the order of a few pennies a month, maybe less.

Comment: You are correct, I was misreading. Thanks for pointing it out, I think I will just have it trigger every time.

Comment: how about adding a wait time in lambda ??