# S3 trigger to perform a file conversion for a multi-part file type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipartfile

I am working on converting shapefiles to geojson. Shapefiles are composed of at least 3 required files and as many as 8 separate files all residing in a folder.  To convert to geojson you need all the constituent parts. Right now I have a batch conversion process that goes through all the shapefiles stored in an s3 bucket, downloads all the separate file parts and performs the conversion.  What I'm trying to figure out now is how to run the file conversion process based on the upload of a single shapefile folder, hopefully using an s3 bucket trigger.

I have reviewed this answer ([AWS - want to upload multiple files to S3 and only when all are uploaded trigger a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376697/aws-want-to-upload-multiple-files-to-s3-and-only-when-all-are-uploaded-trigger)) but in my case there is no frontend client (the answer presented in that question appears to be to signal a final event, but that is done from the client interface).  Maybe I need to build one, but I was trying to handle this only in the backend (there is no frontend and no plans to have one).  The 'user' would be dropping the files right into s3 directly without a file upload interface.

Of course when someone uploads a folder with all the shapefile parts in it, it triggers the s3 trigger for each part but each part cannot produce a shapefile alone.

A few solutions I thought of but with their own problems:

1. I am converting the shapefiles to geojson and storing the geojson in a separate s3 bucket using a naming convention for the geojson based on the s3 file name.  In theory you could always check if the geojson exists in the destination s3 bucket already and if not, run the conversion.  But this still doesn't take care of the timing aspect of all the multiple parts of the file being uploaded. I could check the name but it would be triggered multiple times, fail on some and then ultimately (probably) succeed after all the parts are in place.

1a. Maybe some type of try/except error checking on the conversion mentioned above? meaning, for each file part uploaded, go ahead and try to download and convert. This seems fragile and potentially error prone. Also, I believe that a certain subset of all the files will likely produce a geojson without error but without all the metadata or complete set of data so a successful conversion may not actually be a success.

2. Using a database to track which files have been converted, which would basically be the same solution as 1 above.
3. Partly a question as a solution: on the s3 web console there is 'file' upload and 'folder' upload. To upload the shapefile folder containing all the component parts, you'd have to use the 'folder' option.  The question then is, is there any way to know, from the event trigger perspective, that the operation was a folder upload, not just a file upload and to therefore wait until all the parts of the folder are uploaded OR if there is any event data in AWS that, when a FOLDER is uploaded it counts the underlying file parts (1 of 6, 2 of 6 etc) and could send an event after all the parts of the folder have been uploaded(?)

I also am aware of the 'multipart' upload which would, I think, do what I proposed in #3 above but that multipart 'tag' is only if you upload via sdk or cli. Unless the s3 console folder upload is underneath a multi-part upload?

Comment: Probably sensible to restrict use of the term "mutli-part" here to the S3 feature whereby a single S3 object can be uploaded in multiple parts (or chunks). So, let's say that someone dropped the various constituent files of a shapefile into a folder and you were monitoring that folder and you had the ability to read any/all of the constituent files. How would you know when you had the entire shapefile?

Comment: A folder upload, regardless of how it's done, is just several object uploads.  There is no concept of "the folder" being done, except in the client.  I'd argue any realistic solution needs the client to trigger somehow that it's done.  Either that's a lambda, a custom server, or something else.  Otherwise, you can never know that a client is "done" but forgot/failed/vanished to upload some component file you need.

Comment: @AnonCoward so I take it your saying uploading via s3 console on aws web would not be viable at all; That there has to be a some client side mechanism for this to work. ?

Comment: Yes.  Something on the client must trigger the "you have all the parts" even if that's a link the user clicks on.  Otherwise the server side would need to guess, and there are no doubt edge cases where that'll fail